# How to duplicate rows but change the value in a specific column postgresql - redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that I need to duplicate for the next 13 weeks. However, in one specific column, the date needs to update.

My Data::

table1

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    date
110010  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  07-Jun
110011  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  08-Jun
110012  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  09-Jun
110013  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  10-Jun
110014  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  11-Jun
110015  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  12-Jun
110016  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  13-Jun
```

The data needs to be duplicated but the date column should update.

Expected output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    date
110010  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  07-Jun
110011  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  08-Jun
110012  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  09-Jun
110013  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  10-Jun
110014  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  11-Jun
110015  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  12-Jun
110016  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  13-Jun
110010  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  14-Jun
110011  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  15-Jun
110012  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  16-Jun
110013  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  17-Jun
110014  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  18-Jun
110015  axbe    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  19-Jun
110016  axbc    ORT.01  +   ACTIVE  20-Jun
..........................
..........................
```

I tried using a cross join in Redshift but I'm getting incorrect/inconsistent data.

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,updated_Date

from table1

cross join (select distinct dateadd('day',91,date) as updated_Date)
```

Comment: you mean you want to insert the copy of record by adding 13 week in date field

Comment: yes, next 13 weeks dates

Comment: Is this one time task?

Comment: No. its recurring

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with a solution. Since I'm not a `postgresql` pro, you may get better solutions by the others or may be able to get this improved by yourself.

I'll use `interval '7' day` mechanism repeatedly for 13 weeks. I tried to define a variable and do it in a loop, (or cursor) which was not succussful.

See the following works for you:

Leave the data already in the table as it is and create another table to put the created data.

```
Insert into t2
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, col6 from t
union
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, col6 + interval '7' day as col6 from t
union
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, col6 + interval '14' day as col6 from t
....
;
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a3e833a32ea6d0e6dcea4368371a1806)